# Talend DI : extract many pairs of rows from a log file (using regex)

Tags: regex, csv, extract, rows, talend

I am using `TALEND DATA INTEGRATION`

I have a log file like this

```
I - Fab - 392 - 2014/12/20 22:09:15:200 - XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX Begin : 

I - Fab - 392 - 2014/12/20 22:12:15:438 - XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX Bus / Before :

500|00104|002PL|0036364043        |005PL

809|001BBG|00365   |005-0200|006+0000|007000|0080000|0240|0250|0260|0270|0280|0290|033STK|034063100       |0441

830|0093100       |0441

I - Fab - 392 - 2014/12/20 22:12:19:766 - XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX Bus / After : 

500|00104|002PL|0036364043        |005PL

510|001BBG|00365   |005-0200|006+0000|007000|0080000|0240|0250|0260|0270|0280|0290|033STK|034063100       |0441
```

I want to extract the lines 2&3 and 6&7 (it's not always pair and impair). Anyway, I used a regular expression :

`"I - (Fab|Opt) - \\d+ - (\\d{4}/\\d{2}/\\d{2}) (\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{3}) - .+ Bus / (.+) : \\n500|.+|003(\\d{7}).+"`

using a `tFileInputRegex`, however I don't know what to use in the row separator (by default `"\n"`)

I want my output to be a CSV file in which there are data extracted from the first and second lines.

I used a tMap to generate a CSV file, but the problem is I cannot extract the data I want.

If I extract the data I want I will be able to generate the file. So, I need help in the regex part. I wonder if there's a way in Talend DI to extract multiple rows (in my case TWO) using `tFileInputRegex`.

**EDIT :**

I have specified `I -` as a row separator, so I can be able to use `\n` (without any confusion), but the regex doesn't seem functional.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want your output CSV to look like?

Comment: The CSV file header is like : `OptOrFab;Date;Time;Step;Job`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\n` delimiter for multiline (rows) should work, so it's more an issue of your overall regex. Try using a pattern such as this, for it should capture the groups correctly:

```
I.+(Fab|Opt).+(\\d{4}\\/\\d{2}\\/\\d{2}).+(\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{3}).+Bus\\s\\/\\s(\\w+)\\s:\\W+\\n500.+003(\\d{7}).+
```

Example:

**https://www.regex101.com/r/nL2xT7/**

Comment: Still doesn't work. I have already been able to extract the data of the first row. The problem is when I add the `\n`. Besides, in the description of `tFileInputRegex`, it is said that this element reads the file row by row and extracts fields using regular expressions. Doesn't that mean that I can't read two lines ?

Comment: try adding another `\n`, or removing it altogether.

Comment: I have specified `I -` as a row separator, so I can be able to use `\n` (without any confusion), but the regex doesn't seem functional.

Comment: Show the output you're getting with the regex in my answer. Also, are the empty rows in between the text there as well? If they are then that would be part of the issue too.